# Laravel | Model / Database convention not working as expected

Tags: database, laravel, model, eloquent, naming-conventions

As mentioned in the title, I am encountering an issue concerning the convention between models and database. I created a new model named "Media". In my database, I created a new table named "medias".

Following the documentation, Laravel is assuming the table name should be the plural of the model name. In my case, it is actually not working, I need to set manually the property table in order to get the desired behavior.

Laravel version : 5.3
Mamp | php 7.0.13

I will really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Welcome! This is actually more of a linguistic question, take a look at [What is the plural of media?](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/02/plural-of-media/). Laravel is pretty smart in terms of pluralization :)

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake few minutes ago when i saw the answers to this discussion, I speak french so i didn't think about this simple linguistic problem because in french there is a plural of media... thank you for your time.

Comment: I understand it well, English isn't my native language either. Now as your doubt has been clarified, you can accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

`Media` is an exception. Laravel is smart enough to know that there is no plural for `media`. So you should create `media` table instead.

You can see all exceptions [here](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php):

```
Words that should not be inflected.

private static $uninflected = array(
    ....
    '?*media',
    ....
);
```

Comment: I was struggling with this simple issue because in french there is a plural of "media" which is "medias" as you may expected. I didn't think about the difference between language, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Media** is the plural form of **Medium**.

So either you can create a table with `media` name or in your Media model you can write this,

```
protected $table = 'medias';
```